# React cascade rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got `react-toastify` element in my `App.js` component implemented this way:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { toast } = this.props
    if(toast.id !== prevProps.toast.id) {
      this.notify(toast)
    }
  }

  notify = (data) => {
    switch(data.type) {
      case TOAST.TYPE.ERROR:
        ...
        return toast.show()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <div className="app">
          <Switch>
            <Route path={ getRoutePath('password.set') } component={ PasswordSet } />
            <Route path={ getRoutePath('password.reset') } component={ PasswordReset } />
            <Route path={ getRoutePath('login') } component={ LoginSection } />
            <Route path={ getRoutePath('home') } component={ AuthenticatedSection } />
          </Switch>
          <ToastContainer 
            className="custom-toastify" 
            autoClose={ 5000 } 
            hideProgressBar={ true }
            closeButton={ <CloseButton /> } 
          />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ toast }) {
  return { toast }
}
```

Now consider the following scenario: I've got a `UsersAdmin` PureComponent inside `AuthenticatedSection` where you can enable/disable users. When you click on enable/disable button, the `UsersAdmin` component re-renders because of `users` redux state change and then it also re-renders, because I'm showing toast on success/error api call.

```
toggleUsersDisabled = (user) => () => {
        const { modifyUser, showToast } = this.props
        modifyUser(user.id, {
            disabled: user.disabled === 0 ? 1 : 0
        }).then((response) => {
            showToast(`${response.value.name} has been ${response.value.disabled ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'}`)
        }).catch(_noop)
    }
```

The showToast dispatches new message to redux state for toasts. Is it possible to somehow prevent re-rending of child components when the toast is shown?

Edit:
added UsersAdmin redux connection including selector

```
// users selector
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const getUsers = state => state.users.get('data')
const getIsFulfilled = state => state.users.get('isFulfilled')

export const getFulfilledUsers = createSelector(
    [getUsers, getIsFulfilled],
    users => users
)

// UsersAdmin
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        users: getFulfilledUsers(state)
    }
}


UsersAdmin.propTypes = {
    users: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    fetchUsersList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    modifyUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    showToast: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUsersList, modifyUser, deleteUser, showToast })(UsersAdmin)
```

Comment: The Toast changes to the state should not affect other elements. Can you show how you connect UsersAdmin to the redux store, including your selectors?

Comment: @eronisko take a look at the edited part of the question :)

Comment: "it also re-renders" what also re-renders? Can you show the child components that you don't want to re-render? Create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on https://codesandbox.io/s/new if possible.

Comment: Is it a rerender or a remount?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why you added all the toasts login inside your `App.js`

if you look over the docs in:
https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify#installation

the only thing you need to do is adding `<ToastContainer />` to your app and you are done, exactly like you have in your example.

Now for calling toasts you just import:

```
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
```

in to any component you like in the system, and now you just run the `toast` function and you got yourself a toast.

ie:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
    showToast() {
        toast('you now see a toast');
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={()=>this.showToast()}>toast it</button>;
    }
}
```